# Javascript how to remove prototype methods from a data object or make objects work with Qunit equals

Tags: javascript, jquery, qunit

I've started working with Qunit to do unit testing on my code, but am striking problems comparing objects.

The code I'm testing dynamically creates an object:

```
var fields = ['id','name'];
var result = {};
for (var field in fields)
{
    var name = fields[field];
    result[name] = name;
}

var expected = { id : 'id', name : 'name' };

test(expected, result, "same ?");
```

This test fails, and I can see that while expected just contains the fields id and name, result also contains a whole lot of functions, eg

```
"function (iterator, context) {...
```

I think these functions come from me treating the object like an array in order to assign to it.

Is there a way to strip these functions out (or prevent them from getting added in the first place)?

I was thinking of doing

```
result = $.parseJSON($.toJSON(result));
```

is there a better way?

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm using jquery and prototype libraries, not sure if these are the cause of the additional object properties.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with jQuery or Prototype.  JavaScript's native `for in` construct will unearth every single object property, including inherited ones.  For arrays, always use the conventional `for` loop if you're only after the array elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check the type of each object in the collection to see if it's a function:

```
if(typeof fields[field] == 'function') continue;
```

Also, ***don't use `for..in` on arrays***:

```
for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
   result[result[i]] = result[i];
}
```

What you have there isn't strictly an *object*, it's an `Array` object, which is nevertheless an object, but not in the sense that it has key-value pairs.

If you use a vanilla `for` loop, you will not iterate through the prototype chain as you do with `for..in`, so maybe doing that might solve your problem.

Comment: I'd prefer not to rewrite qunit's equals function if possible. Then the only other way to use that would be to iterate over, and delete result[name] if it's a function, but I thought there would be a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: There is always `hasOwnProperty()` (not that I condone its use) :)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is your use of `for...in`, which is iterating over everything `fields` is inheriting from `object`. If you must keep `for...in`, you can modify it like this:

```
for (var field in fields){
  if( fields.hasOwnProperty( field ) ){
    var name = fields[field];
    result[name] = name;
  }
}
```

`hasOwnProperty` returns true if the specified property of the object (and the array *is* an object) is not inherited.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `for in` on Arrays.  Chapter 6 of [JavaScript: The Good Parts](http://www.scribd.com/doc/15490908/JavaScript-The-Good-Parts-by-OReilly-Media) provides a great explanation:

> Since JavaScript's arrays are really
>   objects, the `for in` statement can be
>   used to iterate over all of the
>   properties of an array. Unfortunately,
>   `for in` makes no guarantee about the
>   order of the properties, and most
>   array applications expect the elements
>   to be produced in numerical order.
>   **Also, there is still the problem with
>   unexpected properties being dredged up
>   from the prototype chain.**

Use the conventional C-style `for` loop instead.